# node.js and Cygein for windows, how do I run code?

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, cygwin

I've installed WAMP and cygwin. From cygwin I'm trying to run a .js I made but I don't know where to save it to. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Got it cygwin/home/user/node-v0.4.2